# Retrieve data from multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, otrs

Here are list of arrays which i echoed in

`Array
    (
    [CustomerID] => manish14
    [TicketID] => 45691
    [TicketNumber] => 1045828
    [CustomerUserID] =>
    )
 Array
(
[CustomerID] => ghisingraaz@gmail.com
[TicketID] => 45686
[TicketNumber] => 1045823
[CustomerUserID] => ghisingraaz@gmail.com
)
Array
(
[CustomerID] => ranjana@classic.com.np
[TicketID] => 45661
[TicketNumber] => 1045798
[CustomerUserID] => ranjana@classic.com.np
)
........
........
........`

I want to display customerID , TicketID and TicketNumber of each array in a  table format. How can i retrieve those values. I have this in multiple foreach loop thats why i am having problem getting those values.
Here is my code incase anyone wants to see.  phpfiddle.org/main/code/wb4u-nrsj

You can find my code in [this PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wb4u-nrsj).

Comment: Can you explain Properly using fiddle code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(0);
//////// OTRS specific information ////////
$url = "https://otrs.classic.com.np/otrs/rpc.pl"; //// URL for OTRS server
$username = "ctdeveloper"; //// SOAP username set in sysconfig
$password = "ctdeveloper"; //// SOAP password set in sysconfig
$TicketID = $_GET['id'];
########################################################################
#### You don't have to change anything below here, although you can ####
########################################################################
#### Initialize new client session ####
echo "<table><tr><th>CustomerID</th><th>TicketID</th><th>TicketNumber</th></tr>";
$client = new SoapClient(
    null,
    array(
        'location' => $url,
        'uri' => "Core",
        'trace' => 1,
        'login' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'style' => SOAP_RPC,
        'use' => SOAP_ENCODED
    )
);

#### Initialize new client session ####
$client = new SoapClient(
    null,
    array(
        'location' => $url,
        'uri' => "Core",
        'trace' => 1,
        'login' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'style' => SOAP_RPC,
        'use' => SOAP_ENCODED
    )
);

$queues = array(1 => "Postmaster",
    2 => "Raw",
    3 => "Junk",
    4 => "Retail Support",
    5 => "Enterprise Support",
    6 => "Sales",
    7 => "Marketing",
    8 => "Fiber Survey",
    9 => "Fiber Support",
    10 => "Billing",
    11 => "NOC",
    12 => "Wireless Support",
    13 => "Core-Tasks",
    14 => "Chitwan",
    15 => "Developer",
    16 => "Operations",
    17 => "Administration",
    18 => "Hetauda",
    19 => "Business",
    20 => "Info",
    21 => "Corporate",
    22 => "Wireless Survey",
    23 => "Recovery",
    24 => "L2-Support",
);

foreach ($queues as $queue_number => $queue_name) {
#### Create and send the SOAP Function Call ####
    $TicketDetail_search = $client->__soapCall("Dispatch",
        array($username, $password,
            "TicketObject", "TicketSearch",
            "Result", "ARRAY",
            "UserID", 1,
            "QueueIDs", array($queue_number),
            "StateType", "open"
        ));

    // REMOVE s-gensym
    $ticketInfo = array();
    if ($TicketDetail_search) {
        foreach ($TicketDetail_search as $name => $value){
            if (false !== strpos($name, "s-gensym"))
            {
                    $ticketInfo[] = $value;
            }
        }   
    }

    foreach($ticketInfo as $TicketID)
    {
        $TicketDetail_get = $client->__soapCall("Dispatch",
            array($username, $password,
                "TicketObject", "TicketGet",
                "TicketID", $TicketID,
            ));
        foreach($TicketDetail_get as $t)
        {
            $ticketInfo1 = array();
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($TicketDetail_get as $name => $value){ // explode the xml response
                if (false !== strpos($name, "s-gensym")){
                    $temp[$i] = $value;
                    if($i > 0) {
                        $v = $temp[$i-1];
                        if($i % 2 != 0){
                            $ticketInfo1[$v] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    $i++;
                }

            }

        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $ticketInfo1['CustomerID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $ticketInfo1['TicketID'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $ticketInfo1['TicketNumber'] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";





    }


    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: It didnt help. Here is my code .  phpfiddle.org/main/code/wb4u-nrsj

Comment: does this even output anything on here ?

Comment: I am working in an OTRS project. I am using soap api to call the data. I just want to retrieve customerID , TicketID and TicketNumber from above list of arrays.

Comment: I fixed it for you:

Comment: Your answer helped me get my desired solution. THank You. I got the result by using  one extra step than yours i.e array_merge to merge the arrays